# What is a parametrized surface? How is it different from a surface? (Multivariable Calculus)

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

My textbook defines it like this:

Let F be a continuous function from a subset D(F) R<sup>2</sup> into R<sup>q</sup>. Suppose that D(F) is pathwise connected, and that every point in D(F) is either an interior point of D(F), or on the boundary of the interior of D(F).  Then F is called a **parametrized surface** in R<sup>q</sup>.

I understand what everything in the definition means and understand how to check for all the conditions.  However, I do NOT understand what type of surface is being described.  How do these special qualities of the domain enhance our understanding of the surface?

Can someone explain what a parametrized surface is (intuitively, not formally) and how that relates to this formal definition?

What consequences are their to a surface being a "parametrized surface?"

Comment: I think this link gives a good intuitive and visual overview: http://mathinsight.org/parametrized_surface_introduction

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways I like to think about surfaces: 1) as graphs of functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, 2) as level sets of functions $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and 3) as images of maps $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.  Surfaces of the third type are called parametric.

Here are examples of each:

1) The graph of $z = x^2 + y^2$ is a paraboloid.

2) The sphere is the level set $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$.  Here the function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is $F(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$.  Note that the graph of $F$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^4$, but that when we take a level of $F$ (i.e., set it equal to a constant) it becomes a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

3) The torus (surface of a donut) is a parametric surface that can be defined as the image of the map $G:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ given be $G(u,v) = ((2 + cos(v))cos(u), (2 + cos(v))sin(u), sin(v))$.  Here, the input variables $u$ and $v$ are called parameters, and the output coordinates could be specified as three "parametric equations":

x = (2 + cos(v))cos(u)

y = (2 + cos(v))sin(u)

z = sin(v)

As $u$ and $v$ take on different values, the function $G$ traces out the surface in space.

There's more to say here, but that's a start!

Comment: A further point: these three different descriptions are often, but not always, compatible.  For example, the paraboloid can be expressed in all three ways.  It's a level set $x^2 + y^2 - z = 0$.  It's also a parametric surface defined by $G(u,v) = (u, v, u^2 + v^2)$.  Neither the sphere nor the torus, however, are graphs of functions from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ (they fail the vertical line test.)